# How can I find the newest files in a specific folder and all of it's subfolders in a cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to keep my database updated, so every time I get the latest files from TFS I want to find the changed files (newest in date) in order to run them and not run **ALL** of the files.
I want to create a batch file to search, find and copy them to a temp folder so I'll be able to run only them.

Answer (score 0):

A creative solution would be you can enter `dir` results into a text file and then whichever language you are using just do string slicing which can give u date, memory and name of the file. This is command- `dir/a>file` replace file with the text file. if u want the text to be entered into the file in append mode then `dir/a>>file`

Comment: PS: the batch script's directory should be same as directory of the files. cd command is used for changing directory